# how to modify global variable in an subdirectory

Tags: python, global-variables, python-import

I am currently working on a project with multiple files and created a shared variables file for all the global variables I need.
everything seemed to be working fine until I tried modifying a global variable from within a subdirectory.
the layout of my projects looks something like this:

- projects/
- projects/shared_variables.py
- projects/main.py
  -projects/logic2
- projects/subDir
- projects/subDir/logic.py

the code in them looks something like this:

**shared_variables.py:**

```
# this file contains all the global variables for the project
foo = "initialized"
```

**main.py:**

```
from myproject import shared_variables
from myproject.subDir.logic import do_something
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"foo variable in main:{shared_variables.foo} foo id:{id(shared_variables.foo)}")
    do_something()
```

**logic.py:**

```
import myproject.shared_variables
def do_something():
    myproject.shared_variables.foo = 5#doing something
    print(f"foo variable in logic:{myproject.shared_variables.foo} logic id:{id(myproject.shared_variables.foo)}")
```

the output of the code is:

```
foo variable in main:initialized foo id:4426951216 
foo variable in logic:5 logic id:4423687024
```

so basically when to import the foo variable and use it in any other files like logic2 which are on the same directory everything works fine and I get the same id(in this case 4426951216) but whenever I try to make changes to foo in the subdirectory (subDir) the changes don't pass for the rest of the project and by the looks of it its because logic initializes shared_variables.py again.
I have already tried defining init() function in shared_variables and calling it in main.py but in this case, i get a variable not found error(foo) only in logic.py

Comment: `id` is giving you the identifier for the *value* of the name; it's not associated with the name itself. `5` and `"initialized"` are two separate values.

Comment: See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: it still doesn't explain why  when I change the value of the global variable foo in logic.py it doesn't change the value in the other modules